# MYSQL Match example not working. Is "Spa" a stopword?

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE match(fieldname) against('spa')
```

I don't understand why this query doesn't return any results.
It should find at least 10 rows with the word spa in. Spa isn't a keyword/stop word is it?

Comment: Don't you need min. 4 chars word for match against?

Comment: Do you have a fulltext index on `fieldname`? Is the column case-sensitive?

Comment: Thanks. That makes perfect sense, but instead of resetting the system variable I will add some exceptions to certain 3 character keywords into my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The minimum and maximum lengths of words to be indexed are defined by the ft_min_word_len and ft_max_word_len system variables. **The default minimum value is four characters**; the default maximum is version dependent. If you change either value, you must rebuild your FULLTEXT indexes. For example, if you want three-character words to be searchable, you can set the ft_min_word_len variable by putting the following lines in an option file:

```
[mysqld]
ft_min_word_len=3
```

Then restart the server and rebuild your FULLTEXT indexes. Note particularly the remarks regarding myisamchk in the instructions following this list.

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html

Answer (score 0):

No, spa is not one of the default stopwords but there is a minimum word length in the MySQL full-text search which I believe defaults to 4: [ft_min_word_length](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len)

Answer (score 0):

There is a minimum length of four character for the searching.  However, it appears that the search capability can be altered

[Fine-Tuning MySQL Full-Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html)

> MySQL's full-text search capability has few user-tunable parameters.
>   You can exert more control over full-text searching behavior if you
>   have a MySQL source distribution because some changes require source
>   code modifications. See Section 2.17, “Installing MySQL from Source”.
>
> Note that full-text search is carefully tuned for the most
>   effectiveness. Modifying the default behavior in most cases can
>   actually decrease effectiveness. Do not alter the MySQL sources unless
>   you know what you are doing.
>
> Most full-text variables described in this section must be set at
>   server startup time. A server restart is required to change them; they
>   cannot be modified while the server is running.
>
> Some variable changes require that you rebuild the FULLTEXT indexes in
>   your tables. Instructions for doing so are given later in this
>   section.
>
> The minimum and maximum lengths of words to be indexed are defined by
>   the ft_min_word_len and ft_max_word_len system variables. (See Section
>   5.1.3, “Server System Variables”.) The default minimum value is four characters; the default maximum is version dependent. If you change
>   either value, you must rebuild your FULLTEXT indexes. For example, if
>   you want three-character words to be searchable, you can set the
>   ft_min_word_len variable by putting the following lines in an option
>   file:

```
[mysqld] 
ft_min_word_len=3
```

> Then restart the server and rebuild your
>   FULLTEXT indexes. Note particularly the remarks regarding myisamchk in
>   the instructions following this list.